# Panning and zooming over a large image just like in Bing Map control

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am looking for a solution where I am able to do all the gestures (flick, pinch, drag) with a **local picture** in my Windows Phone 7 application with acceptable performance. The Silverlight Bing Map control for WP7 does all of this perfectly, but it cannot do this with a **local image**.

I started to write my own control, but I was wondering if there is anything out there written by someone else. Is there anything out there?

Is it possible to reuse the Map control, but with my own image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laurent Bugnion's Multitouch Behaviour from beta might also be worth a look for this purpose.

[MultiTouch Behavior for Windows Phone 7](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/07/04/multitouch-behavior-for-windows-phone-7-videos-wp7dev.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+galasoft+%28Laurent+Bugnion+%28GalaSoft%29%29&utm_content=Twitter)

[MultiTouch Behavior: Update for Windows Phone 7 tools beta](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/07/12/multitouch-behavior-update-for-windows-phone-7-tools-beta.aspx)

Comment: I tried this one and found that the performance on real device is not really good. I will try to contact the author and get some information on that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a [MultiScaleImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage%28VS.95%29.aspx). You can use this with [DeepZoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28VS.95%29.aspx).

There's an (old) example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/03/28/deep-zoom-on-wp7.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem with MultiScalImage is that it can only take an image from the net. I am looking for a solution where the source image is local to the application.